# Embedded Java Applet Returns NullPointerException in JSPX pages

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception, jdeveloper, jspx

We have a ADF web application programmed in JDeveloper 11g (11.1.2.4.0), which was migrated over from a 10g (10.1.3.5.0) project

Within the application, occasionally, we need to call a Java Applet which is placed in a public_html/applet folder. The jars show up in the Web-Content tab of the ViewController in the Application Navigator, just like it did in 10g.

The applet tag looks like this:

```html
<applet height="100" width="100" 
    code="applet.SetupApplet" archive="applet/SSetupApplet.jar">
            <param name="debug" value="true"/>
```

I've also tried calling the applet with the Java deploy applet script

```xml
<trh:script source="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></trh:script>
    <trh:script>
        var attributes = {code:'applet.SetupApplet',
        archive:'applet/SSetupApplet.jar'};
        var parameters = {} ;
        var version = '1.6' ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
   </trh:script>
```

When I navigate to the login.jspx page that has this tag, it pops the Java Console open, but doesn't actually run the applet (or show the prompts to allow using the Applet). Instead, the applet is shown with an error and the Application error says `NullPointerException`; there's no error shown in the Java Console. I've double-checked the path and it's correct (with incorrect paths, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`). In the application server logs, I see the following error:

```
<Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on IPADDRESS during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
```

I created a normal .jsp file that's outside the ADF Faces Context in the applet folder. Navigating to it with the same applet tags does have the Java applet run without the socket error. The same code in 10g works fine.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Frank's article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/71-adf-to-applet-communication-307672.pdf . He explains how to embed the applet and at the end of the article how to configure the browser.

Comment: Okay, Frank's article actually did fix it. The key thing was that I was pathing it wrong. The applet cannot be called within the "faces" path. Once it was outside the "faces" url, the applet started loading.

P.S. The closing socket error continued even when the applet works properly. Red Herring!